# Would combining essential oils and carrier oils be okay in terms of flash point?

Tags: mixtures

With NO scientific, or chemical background, I am making my own beard oils. I found essential oil recipes online to mix with one or many carrier oils to make beard oil. I want to be original by going out on a limb and exploring other scents besides sandalwood, cedar, pine forest, bergamot, patchouli etc etc etc. I get so burned out seeing and smelling the same scents over and over.

With all of that out of the way, I want to combine some essential oils and carrier oils, and then mix in one of the three following oils to make an awesome scent like no other before this. The three following oils are from Crafter's Choice (if that matters.)
The three oils to choose from are

- Butterscotch fragrance
- Pink Cotton Candy fragrance
- Double Bubble Gum (this one is actually a flavor)

I see on the bottles that these all have a flash-point. I'm guessing that has something to do with combustion at a known flash-point temp.

My main worry is, can I combine these flavor and fragrance oils with carrier oils, and or essential oils without worrying about some crazy Frankenstein mad scientist Yosemite Sam mishap on my face at some point in the day.

Would combining these oils be okay?

Comment: Personal medical questions are off-topic. We won't speculate on how to formulate health care products that should be formulated with appropriate research and testing, and not formulated by guesswork. This policy is exactly to avoid "some crazy Frankenstein mad scientist Yosemite Sam mishap."